# usermod change the username

Tags: username

I tried this command

```
root@node1:~# usermod -l node1admin serveradmin -d /home/node1admin -m
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN
```

It keeps saying I have wrong command. The help provides only the options, doesn't really tell me the format. But where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to change `serveradmin`'s name to `node1admin`, use this instead:

```
usermod -l node1admin -m -d /home/node1admin serveradmin
```

In particular, the name of the user account you're *operating on* should be last, as the general syntax for [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/usermod.8.html) is:

```
usermod [options] LOGIN
```

Answer (score 2):

As the usage line explains, the current username (LOGIN) must be the last argument of the command.